# Tree with grouping of edges

Tags: forest

I know how to draw a `$k$-tree` of just single level, but I also need the grouping of the edges. See the diagram below:

[image]

This is what I am trying:

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={l+=0.08cm} % increase level distance
  [1
    [2
       [4][5]
    ]
    [3
       [6][7]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with a few braces. The way the endpoints of the brace is defined is called a "nodewalk" I think. I probably can't explain it better than the `forest` manual, so read the example that starts at the bottom of page 8, starting with "Finally, the most powerful tool", and also 3.8.7 on page 57. (Page references are given based on the manual to version 2.1.5 of `forest`, dated July 14 2017.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
  Brace/.style={
      decoration={
         brace,
         mirror,
         amplitude=5pt,
         raise=#1 % use argument to style to determine how far the brace is moved
      },
      decorate
  },
  % set the default argument to 0
  Brace/.default=0
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={l+=0.08cm} % increase level distance
  [1
    [2
       [4]
       {
          \draw [Brace] (.south west) -- (!>>>>.south east);
          \draw [red,Brace=5pt] (.south west) -- (!>>>.south east);
          \draw [blue,Brace=10pt] (.south west) -- (!s.south east);
       }
       [5]
       {
          \draw [orange,Brace=15pt] (.south west) -- (!uu21.south east);
       }
    ]
    [3
       [6]
       {
          \draw [cyan,Brace=10pt] (.south west) -- (!s.south east);
       }
       [7]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 'Relative node names' might be helpful if the OP looks in the manual, too.